# Summation exercise — how can I translate the problem statement into the Wolfram Language?

Tags: summation, education

I'm new to both *Mathematica* and this forum, so this will be my first post here. I just got into *Mathematica* today, and I've been doing some exercises. Up to now things have been going well, but I've become stuck on this specific exercise:

> Calculate the sum, use `Sum`, `N`. You have to convert the number to a floating point number in order to recognize it.
>   $$
> 4\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}
> $$

What I do not understand is exactly what the `Sum` function should look like. Also, do I convert the answer I get to a floating point number with `N`?

Comment: Also `4 NSum[(-1)^(k + 1)/(2 k - 1), {k, 1, 1000}]`. You should be able to recognise the number yourself, but if you don't, use `4 Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)/(2 k - 1), {k, 1, ∞}]`.

Comment: This was x-posted on Wolfram Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1540588 (note to poster: when you do that, please add links from each to the other, so that potential responders will know what has already been covered).

Comment: Look also at `RootApproximant[sum/Pi] Pi`

Answer (score 2):

Although you explicitly asked about using `Sum`, please note an alternative way to approach calculating the same thing, without any explicit use of an iterator `{i, 1000}`:

```
f[x_] := 10^(x + 1)/(2 x - 1)
N[Total[f[Range[1000]]]]
(* 5.558953381284399*10^997 *)
```

This is possible because `f` automatically gets the attribute of being `Listable`, so that `f[Range[1000]]` finds "simultaneously" the value of `f` at all the entries in the list `Range[1000]`.

You can avoid all the nested brackets above (which make it hard to read) by using the `Prefix` operator abbreviated by `@`:

```
N @ Total @ f@ Range[1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the exercise should go this way.

```
 Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)/(2 k - 1), {k, 1000}] // N
```

> `0.785148`

This is an approximation of `π/4` as can be inferred from

```
sum = Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)/(2 k - 1), {k, ∞}]
```

> `π/4`

and

```
N[sum]
```

> `0.785373`

Answer (score 0):

You can look up usage etc. of functions in the documentation. eg.: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html

In other words you need to write

```
Sum[f[i], {i,1000}]
```

with f being your function. N can just be applied the yield a number. Refer to the Documentation for further information or feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The way I solved this was by creating a variable and setting it equal to the Sum[] function, and then just typing N[variable], much like in programming. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, N[x] is the same as N@x is the same as x // N (postfix should only be followed by other postfixes)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to understand if you use the Mathematica help pages for Sum and N. I don't understand what you mean by converting the number to a floating point number.

Start by defining

```
f[x_] := 10^(x + 1)/(2 x - 1)
```

Then use:

```
Sum[f[i], {i, 1000}]
```

You get a very big number.

Then type

```
N[%]
```

and you will get the number in floating point format. I get

5.558953381284399*10^997

Comment: You are right. The thing that confused me was the instruction to convert the sum into a floating point number, since the sum of the function is very long. I used 
    sumLargeValue = 4 *Sum[(-1^(k + 1))/(2 k - 1), {k, 1000}] and then I used 
    N[sumLargeValue] to print the floating point sum.